# Create Word/PDF files from Excel content

Tags: scripting, excel-2010

I have an Excel file that I want to split into several files (Word, PDF is also good), based on content. The content is somewhat like this:

```
Person  Fase  Date       Item  Text
A       1     01-01-2012 Z     Lorem ipsum
A       2     01-02-2012 X     Lorem ipsum
B       1     02-01-2012 Y     Lorem ipsum
C       2     01-01-2012 Z     Lorem ipsum
```

I want Word/PDF documents with names like

```
Person_Fase.docx
```

And as content the date, item and text. Idealy in a table layout. Any hints/ clues on how to get there? It's about 700 clients, with up to 300 Excel entries each.

Answer (score 0):

A trick I have used in the past was to create HTML documents, replacing the tab delimited file by an HTML table. This HTML file can be opened by MS Word, and *maybe* even renamed to .docx, even though it is HTML.

Another way to do it is to use VBScript and build proper Office documents.

Download ofhtml9.exe from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa155477(v=office.10).aspx for more info. There are some proprietary attributes to format the HTML files for Office.

Good Luck!